# Question about R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read a proof about submodules of a free module.
Let $R$ a PID, $F$ = free $R$-module and $0 \neq L \leq_R F$ a $R$-submodule of $F$.

Let $F' = Re_1 + Re_2 + \dots + Re_{n-1}$, where $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis of $F$.

Somewhere in the proof I have that if $L \not\subset F'$, then $L \cap F' \leq F'$ then we have $\color{red}{\frac{L+F'}{F'} \leq \frac{F}{F'}}$. My question is: how can I obtain the relation with red color? I know that from second isomorphism theorem I have that $\frac{L+F'}{F'} \simeq \frac{L}{L \cap F'}$. But from there how can I continue? Thanks!

Comment: By Correspondence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem) for $R-$modules you know that $\frac{F}{F'}$submodules  are in correspondence with the submodules  A of $F$ such that $F'\subset A$. In this case $F'\subset F'+L$

Comment: I still can't figure it out..

Comment: What Bongo is saying is that you *know* exactly what the submodules of $F/F'$ are. They are precisely the modules of the form $A/F'$ where $A$ is a submodule of $F$ containing $F'$. In this case, just take $A=F'+L$.

Comment: Oh, ok! So what I understand from this is that $\frac{L+F'}{F'}$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $\frac{F}{F'}$ from Correspondence Theorem, so we can say that $\frac{L+F'}{F'}$ is a submodule of   $\frac{F}{F'}$. Is true what I understood or not?